# Unable to install avconv/libav

Tags: macos, configure, libavcodec, libav, avconv

I'm having no luck install libav on OS X Mavericks. Ive tried everything.

I'm following this guide: http://earthwithsun.com/questions/568464/install-latest-libav-avconv-on-osx

After doing the macport dependency check, which passes, I then run

```
./configure \
--enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid \
--enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb \
--enable-nonfree --enable-libfaac \
--enable-libmp3lame --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx \
--enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libfreetype --enable-doc --enable-gnutls --enable-shared
```

This fails with the following error:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
ERROR: gnutls not found

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
libav-tools@libav.org mailing list or IRC #libav on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solving the problem.
```

**ERROR: gnutls not found**

I've added the path to header files in the environment before running configure, but still no luck

```
export CFLAGS="-I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib"
export CXXFLAGS="-I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib"
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error as you. You need to install gnutls.

I found a how-to here : https://gist.github.com/morgant/1753095

This complete list of commands worked for me (OSX 10.6) :

```
cd ~/Desktop
mkdir wget-build
cd wget-build
curl -O ftp://ftp.gmplib.org/pub/gmp-5.0.2/gmp-5.0.2.tar.bz2
tar xjf gmp-5.0.2.tar.bz2
pushd gmp-5.0.2
CC=gcc-4.2 CXX=g++4.2 ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
popd
curl -O http://www.lysator.liu.se/~nisse/archive/nettle-2.4.tar.gz
tar xzf nettle-2.4.tar.gz
pushd nettle-2.4
CFLAGS="-m64" ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --disable-assembler
make
sudo make install
popd
curl -O http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnutls/gnutls-2.12.12.tar.bz2
tar xjf gnutls-2.12.12.tar.bz2
pushd gnutls-2.12.12
CFLAGS="-m64" CXXFLAGS="-m64" ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --without-p11-kit
make
sudo make install
popd
```

You could also try to use Brew (http://brew.sh/) and install gnutls via :

```
 brew install gnutls
```

Finally a third way that worked for me :

```
curl -O http://libav.org/releases/libav-10.1.tar.gz
tar xjf libav-10.1.tar.gz
cd libav-10.1
./configure
make install
```

Enjoy !

Answer (score 16):

Is "brew install libav" not good enough for your needs ?

Comment: that gave me the error `Error: No available formula for libav` . I;m on mac osx 10.8.5

Comment: Worked for me too

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after reinstallation:

Remove brew from your Mac with the following command: `$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"`

Install it again with: `$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`